# How to evenly distribute a set of list boxes over a grid?

Tags: listview, grid, position, windows-phone-8.1

I'm setting up the View for an application, but I want to distribute the 12 list views evenly over the grid container. At the moment some of the boxes are spaced unevenly in comparison with others, also I'd like to do this without using margins.

I've managed to position the button correctly in the center using the row/column definitions, but not sure how I would leverage that to distribute the list boxes evenly.

Does anyone know how I can set that up using the grid and column settings rather than margins?

This is how I've set up the grid at present, within a grid:

```
<Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="90*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="10*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition />
            <ColumnDefinition />
            <ColumnDefinition />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <ListView x:Name="subjectOneBtn"
                  Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                  Width="211"
                  Height="48"
                  Margin="10,42,0,0"
                  HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                  VerticalAlignment="Top" />
        <ListView x:Name="subjectTwoBtn"
                  Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                  Width="211"
                  Height="48"
                  Margin="10,94,0,0"
                  HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                  VerticalAlignment="Top" />
        <ListView x:Name="subjectThreeBtn"
                  Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                  Width="211"
                  Height="48"
                  Margin="10,171,0,0"
                  HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                  VerticalAlignment="Top" />
        <ListView x:Name="subjectFourBtn"
                  Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                  Width="211"
                  Height="48"
                  Margin="10,223,0,0"
                  HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                  VerticalAlignment="Top" />
        <ListView x:Name="subjectFiveBtn"
                  Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                  Width="211"
                  Height="48"
                  Margin="10,296,0,0"
                  HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                  VerticalAlignment="Top" />
        <ListView x:Name="subjectSixBtn"
                  Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                  Width="211"
                  Height="48"
                  Margin="10,372,0,0"
                  HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                  VerticalAlignment="Top" />
        <ListView x:Name="gradeOneBtn"
                  Grid.Column="2"
                  Width="49"
                  Height="48"
                  Margin="9.333,42,0,0"
                  HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                  VerticalAlignment="Top" />
        <ListView x:Name="gradeTwoBtn"
                  Grid.Column="2"
                  Width="49"
                  Height="48"
                  Margin="9.333,94,0,0"
                  HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                  VerticalAlignment="Top" />
        <ListView x:Name="gradeThreeBtn"
                  Grid.Column="2"
                  Width="49"
                  Height="48"
                  Margin="9.333,171,0,0"
                  HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                  VerticalAlignment="Top" />
        <ListView x:Name="gradeFourBtn"
                  Grid.Column="2"
                  Width="49"
                  Height="48"
                  Margin="9.333,223,0,0"
                  HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                  VerticalAlignment="Top" />
        <ListView x:Name="gradeFiveBtn"
                  Grid.Column="2"
                  Width="49"
                  Height="48"
                  Margin="9.333,296,0,0"
                  HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                  VerticalAlignment="Top" />
        <ListView x:Name="gradeSixBtn"
                  Grid.Column="2"
                  Width="49"
                  Height="48"
                  Margin="9.333,372,0,0"
                  HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                  VerticalAlignment="Top" />
        <Button x:Name="calculateBtn"
                Grid.Row="1"
                Grid.Column="1"
                VerticalAlignment="Center"
                Content="Calculate" />
    </Grid>
```

[image: list box distribution]

Comment: Um... any reason why you are not using a `ComboBox` (XAML app) or `ListPicker` (Silverlight app)? They seem more suitable for your scenario.

Comment: Just changed it to, two combo boxes instead. Seems like a better solution as it allows select by index which is needed in the app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use two StackPanels, the inner one with `Orientation="Horizontal"`. You just need to know how many elements are within a row.

```
<StackPanel>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <ListView.../>
        <ListView.../>
        <ListView.../>
        <ListView.../>
    </StackPanel>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <ListView.../>
        <ListView.../>
        <ListView.../>
        <ListView.../>
    </StackPanel>
    ...
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: There will be two elements in each row, the big and small list view. How would I define that, as in placing them side by side? Also should the StackPanel be outside of the grid?

Comment: Why do you need so many ListViews on one page? Typically one page contains one ListView control to display information. Can you design your page with one ListView and a custom DataTemplate? However, I don't think you can use a ListView control inside a ListItem DataTemplate of a ListView control...

Comment: I need this, as the application takes input of 6 subjects and six associated grades, then the calculate button will calculate the result based on the inputs.

Comment: Or maybe I should be using a different control? The first list on left will hold a list of 12 subjects to pick from, the second will hold grades from A --> F, I'll still need 12 controls though, as the user will have to select 6 combinations of subjects and grades.

Comment: You should think of another way how to achieve this. Let's say your requirements change and you need to grade 20 subjects...the design approach fails here clearly.

Comment: Okay maybe then two list boxes, one for subject and one for grades. Then an "add" buttons adds that combination to the calculation

Comment: Something like that, much better approach as with an unlimited amount of controls in theory ;)